# OrderBy in EF linq to entities can't handle the goodness I'm throwing at it.

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on an app that uses Entity Framework 3.5 and an SQL database. The app searches an object graph based on some search criteria passed down from a user interface. In order to handle the search functionality, I'm using a query builder with the following interface:

```
public interface IQueryBuilder
{
    IQueryable<SomeClass> BuildQuery(Criteria criteria);    
}
```

The criteria object carries several properties that the query builder uses to filter the search results. It also carries a property that dictates how the results should be sorted, called "OrderBy". Here's an example of the criteria object:

```
public class Criteria
{
    //some filter properties...

    public Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>> OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

So, after the initial query has been built, the query builder sorts the query with:

```
var sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(criteria.OrderBy);
```

This works flawlessly in unit tests and integration tests (where it actually hits EF) when I order by a string property (`OrderBy = x => something.LastName`). BUT, when I run integration tests that order by a non-string property (`OrderBy = x => something.AgeInYears`), EF throw the following exception:

`System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.`

In this case, `something.AgeInYears` is an `int`. EF doesn't like the fact that I give it an `int` instead of an `object`.

SO, is there a way I can do what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to (for good reason) make your criteria class like

```
public class Criteria<T, U>
{
    //some filter properties...

    public Expression<Func<T, U>> OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

which should work...so here are a couple of alternatives:

```
public class Criteria<T>
{
    //some filter properties...

    public Expression OrderBy { get; set; }


    public void CreateOrdering<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> value)
    {
        OrderBy = value;
    }
}
```

but since OrderBy isn't generic typed anymore, you'd need to alter your code that applies it:

```
      var orderBy = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "OrderBy",
            new Type[] { query.ElementType, query.ElementType },
            query.Expression,
            criteria.OrderBy);

      var sortedQuery = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderBy
```

alternatively, you could handle this in the code that subsequently applies the ordering:

instead of

```
var sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(criteria.OrderBy);
```

do something like (haven't tested this, but should be basically like this) (UPDATE: this one has no pre-supposition that you're using generics).

```
// grab the property expression out of your ordering statement
var expressionProperty = criteria.OrderBy.Body is UnaryExpression ? (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)criteria.OrderBy.Body).Operand : (MemberExpression)criteria.OrderBy.Body;

// recreate the lambda as Expression<Func<T,U>> where T is the queryable element type and U 
// is the actual type of the property, not an object

var orderBy = Expression.Lambda(expressionProperty, criteria.OrderBy.Parameters.Single());

// apply new lambda instead
var sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. You're right on target. I have changed my question a bit to remove the generics. I added them to make the examples simpler to understand, but I am actually not using generics. Could you please update your answer to assume that I'm not using generics? I am going to go with your last example.

Comment: The second suggestion has no pre-supposition of using generics. I believe it should work as-is.

Comment: BTW, the problem isn't that EF can't handle ordering by ints...it's that it can't handle this (which is what you're giving it) source.OrderBy(i => (object)i.Id);

Answer (score 0):

Check the [methods on the SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466188.aspx) class which can help do LINQ-safe conversions.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer. The problem has nothing to do with SQL translatable functions.